# Problems in Windows 10 after downgrading from Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-10, troubleshooting, windows-11

I updated my Windows 10 laptop to Windows 11 Beta Insider Build today and downgraded back to Windows 10 after using it for a couple hours. After downgrading from Windows 11, Windows seems to have corrupted or something.

After downgrading I deleted all the files in C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download. Then I uninstalled some updates that were updated during the Win 11 upgrade. And I also rolled back my Intel Display adapter to the previous version (because Windows downloads a new one for Win 11 support I guess).

The problems are:

1. When I open the Task Manager and selected the Performance tab, it doesn't show the WiFi graph. After a restart it was back to normal.
2. Then I installed Win Terminal from the store. When I open it from the start menu it doesn't open the Terminal app, but it redirects to MS Store instead. I tried the same thing with another app, but the results were the same.

**I tried resetting the MS Store cache and re-registering it, but neither of those two solutions worked. To solve all these issues I thought of resetting Windows, but later I didn't do it, because I don't want to go through the hassle of reinstalling every single piece of software I had.**

Comment: Golden Rule: Don't run beta software on mission-critical devices without a *full known-good backup*.

Comment: Absolutely correct.  I have Windows 11 on a spare machine.

Comment: At the very least use a dual boot not an upgrade. M$ has been making it more difficult to dual boot but I believe you still can. You have to manually enable the classic text based OS selection menu so Win 10 doesn't half boot up just to show you the OS choices menu.

Answer (score 1):

One of the caveats of Windows Insider is that there is no guarantee you can successfully return to your prior operating system. They do make this clear.

Try a Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

Start with the option to Keep Everything and see if that works.

If not, try again with Keep just Data (Documents) and use the Keep Data option. This keeps your User Profile and all Data but you do have to reinstall software.

If too many issues, you may need to back up and reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: I tried this Get-AppxPackage -allusers | foreach {Add-AppxPackage -register "$($_.InstallLocation)\appxmanifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode} powershell command but it shows some errors to close some apps (Microsoft CBS..). What should I do?